# sqlite3 weird behaviour after error

Tags: windows, sqlite, prompt

Something strange happens when I use sqlite3 from command prompt in Windows. If I do something that gives an error, it keeps echoing "...>" and I can't even quit using the ".quit", the only solution is to close the prompt.

Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sqlite3` shell just waits for the end of the command, which would be indicated with a semicolon.

It might also be necessary to close a string with `'`, or a trigger body with `END;`.